# Graph that joins an odd vertex with an even vertex

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

A graph $G$ has the property that every edge of $G$ joins an odd vertex with an even vertex. Show that $G$ is bipartite and has even size.

Some definitions:

- A vertex of even degree is called an even vertex, while a vertex of odd degree is an odd vertex.
- A graph $G$ is a bipartite graph if $V(G)$ (the set of vertices of $G$) can be partitioned into two subsets $U$ and $W$, such that every edge of $G$ joins a vertex of $U$ and a vertex of $W$.
- Here size refers to the length of the graph, that is, to the number of edges.

What I've tried to do:

So, I've partitioned the set $V(G)$ into two subsets $E$ and $O$, where $E$ consists of the even vertices of $G$ and $O$ consists of the odd vertices of $G$.

By the property that the graph $G$ satisfies it follows that $G$ is bipartite? Do I have to show something else? I'm in doubt because it seems very easy.

Now for the second part of the exercise (G has even size) I know that if $H$ is a bipartite graph of size $m$ with partite sets $U=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_s\}$ and $W=\{w_1,w_2,\ldots, w_t\}$. Since every edge of $H$ joins a vertex of $U$ and a vertex of $W$, it follows that adding the degrees of the vertices in $U$ (or in $W$) gives the number of edges in $H$, that is,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^s \mbox{deg}(u_i) = \sum_{j=1}^t \mbox{deg}(w_j)=m,
$$
where $\mbox{deg}(u)$ is the degree of a vertex $u$ in $H$.

Since $\mbox{deg}(u_i)$ is even for all $i=1,\ldots,s$ it follows that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^s \mbox{deg}(u_i) = m
$$
is even. Am I right? I'm confused because it seems to me that any bipartite graph has even size.

Comment: Why does it seem to you that any bipartite graph has even size? What about the bipartite graphs $K_2$, $K_{1,3}$, $P_4$, $P_6$, $K_{3,3}$, etc. etc. etc.?

Comment: Oh thanks, I get it now. It would take a long time to explain my confusion here. But I was kind of messing around with a result that says every graph has an even number of odd vertices. Anyway, is my proof correct?

Comment: I'm not seeing how the latter lets you conclude that the graph has even size.  The numer $m$ is supposed to be the amount of vertices, not edges, right?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: @GuidoA. $m$ is the number of edges.

Comment: @GuidoA. Some people use the convention (weird and easy to misunderstand, to me) that "size" refers to the number of edges of a graph, while the number of vertices is "order".

Comment: @MishaLavrov I find it a bit counterintuitive. I did delete my answer, but in the moment any bipartite graph $K_{2k,2k+1}$ seemed like an easy 'counterexample'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof:** Since every edge in $G$ joins an odd vertex with an even vertex, it cannot be the case that two odd/even vertices are adjacent. Hence, $G$ is an $X,Y$-bigraph such that $X$ is the set of even vertices, and $Y$ is the set of odd vertices.

We wish to show that $|E(G)|$ is even. Suppose, on the contrary, that $|E(G)|$ is odd. Thus, there are an odd number of edges that are incident to vertices in $X$. This is a contradiction, as each vertex in $X$ is even.

Therefore, if $G$ is a graph such that every edge connects an even and odd vertex, then $G$ is bipartite, and $|E(G)|$ is even.

Comment: I think we wish to show that the number of edges is even, not the number of vertices, though I am not 100% confident here.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thank you for the comment. The proof I had posted was flawed regardless. Ex. $K_{1,2}$ has odd $n(G)$ but satisfies the assumption. $|E(G)|$ being even is a more logical result.